# Haskell not in scope double where clause

Tags: haskell, scope

When i try to compile this it tells me that b is not in scope. Although i already include a where clause for b. Pay no attention to the type synonyms.

```
buildBDD :: BExp -> [ Index ] -> BDD
buildBDD exp inds = snd ( buildBDD' exp 1 inds [])
                  where
                   buildBDD' :: BExp -> Id -> [ Index ] -> [ ( Index, Bool ) ]
                                -> ( Id, BDD )
                   buildBDD' exp ind [] env       
                      = (b, [])
                   buildBDD' exp ind (i : is) env 
                      = buildBDD' exp i is [(ind, True)]
                      where    
                        b = if eval exp env then -1 else -2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `where` scopes to the correct pattern match! Something like `if eval exp env` might not even make sense if you put it to the wrong pattern definition bacause there's e.g. no `env` variable matched at this spot.

```
    buildBDD' exp ind [] env = (b, [])
             where b | eval exp env  = -1
                     | otherwise     = -2                   
    buildBDD' exp ind (i : is) env 
                  = buildBDD' exp i is [(ind, True)]
```

Answer (score 1):

A `where` clause only applies to a single line of definition, so your second `where` clause only applies to the single definition 
`buildBDD' exp ind (i : is) env`. You need to move it up so it is scoped for the previous definition.